# How to Parameterize Test Function: Pytest?

Tags: python, function, testing, pytest

How do I pass a list of data, to a Test Function using Pytest? Each Test Case is pretty similar, except for this input parameter. I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def List_of_Numbers():
    list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


@pytest.parametrize("number", [i for item in list])
def test_eval(number):
    assert eval(number%2) == 0
```

`pytest` output:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________________ ERROR collecting sample4.py __________________________
sample4.py:8: in <module>
@pytest.parametrize("number", [i for item in list])
E   AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'parametrize'
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.30 seconds ============================
```

Comment: It should be `@pytest.mark.parametrize(...)`.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks. Getting the following error now: @pytest.mark.parametrize("number", [i for item in list])
E   TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: That's because your code is wrong. `list` is a built-in class to create new empty lists (as in `x = list()`). In `List_of_Numbers`, you have created a new list, but it is only visible inside the function, so `[i for item in list]` will try to iterate the list class, which raises the error you get. Replace `[i for item in list]` with `range(1, 9)`. BTW, it is a bad practice to create lists named `list` because you overwrite the built-in `list` class. `numbers` would be a better name here.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you ): I've modified the code to your suggestion and it works, but I'm left with the same root issue: how do I pass a list/array of strings as parameters to a Test Function? I've used numbers above to simplify the example. They're dynamic strings. Appreciate it.

Comment: The following works:

`import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def List_of_Numbers():
    numbers = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight"]
    return numbers
    
@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", [i for i in List_of_Numbers()])
def test_eval(number):
    assert number == "One"`

Wondering if there is a more 'elegant' solution. Thanks

Comment: ah, I see - you want to parameterize a test using values returned by a fixture. No, unfortunately there is no way to do that, see [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). Your code will work because you don't use `List_of_Numbers` as a fixture, you just call it as a usual function. Maybe you don't need it to be a fixture at all? Or if `List_of_numbers` is that simple, just declare a global `numbers` list in the script and use it for parametrizing.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with the code:

1. The fixture should be not `@pytest.parametrize`, but `@pytest.mark.parametrize`:

```py
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("number", [i for item in list])
    def test_eval(number):
        assert eval(number%2) == 0
```

2. You are trying to reach variable `list` defined in local scope of another function. Better not to use variable and function names reserved for built-in variables and functions in Python according to common sense and [PEP-8](http://pep8.org).
   You don't need extra fixture just for a list of numbers without any logic. I propose you to use a constant instead:

   `TEST_NUMBERS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`
3. You need to pass a string to `eval`:

`eval(f"{number} % 2")`

Putting it all together:

```py
import pytest


TEST_NUMBERS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", TEST_NUMBERS)
def test_eval(number):
    assert eval(f"{number} % 2") == 0
```

Comment: Show `Putting it all together:` output, It's generating same error for me

Comment: have a you tried `@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", TEST_NUMBERS)` decorator?

Comment: As I said change the decorator to `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

Comment: half baked, 8 failed - TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: @flywire The original question was regarding `parametrize` that's why I ignored the eval. Updated the answer though.