# Using parameters for pytest when parameters depend on each other

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a pytest test for a library similar to this

```
from mylibrary use do_some_calculation
 
def test_df_against_angle():
    df=load_some_df()
    angle=30
    result=do_some_calculation(df,angle)
    assertTrue(result)
```

Now as you can see that test only works for a particular dataframe and for an angle(30)

I have to do this tests for several dataframes and several angles
To complicate matters,the angles I should use are different for each dataset

So I have to test that

- For data_set1.csv I have to try angles 0,30,60
- For data_set2.csv I have to try angles 90,120,150
- For data_set3.csv I have to try angles 180,210,240

So I am guessing that I have to use pytest's parameters for that.
I know how to put simple values as parameters, (So for example I know how to put parameters so as to use those three csv files and even how to put these in a json file and read it to enter the test) but I am at lost as how to put several types of parameters and that these parameters depend on the other

Ideally also I would like to put this in the `conftest.py`

Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Parameterize Test Function: Pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143217/how-to-parameterize-test-function-pytest)

Comment: @ljmc No, I already know how to do that. My question is more complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a function to generate all the test cases:

```py
import pytest


def load_df(filename):
    # TODO: Implement this
    return f"df_{filename}"


def do_some_calculation(df, angle):
    # TODO: Implement this
    return True


def generate_test_data():
    test_combinations = [
        ("data_set1.csv", [0, 30, 60]),
        ("data_set2.csv", [90, 120, 150]),
        ("data_set3.csv", [180, 210, 240]),
    ]

    for filename, angles in test_combinations:
        df = load_df(filename)
        for angle in angles:
            yield df, angle


@pytest.mark.parametrize("df,angle", generate_test_data())
def test_df_against_angle(df, angle):
    result = do_some_calculation(df, angle)
    assert result
```

#### Output

```
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set1.csv-0] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set1.csv-30] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set1.csv-60] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set2.csv-90] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set2.csv-120] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set2.csv-150] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set3.csv-180] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set3.csv-210] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df_data_set3.csv-240] PASSED
```

#### Notes

- The `generate_test_data` function only load the df once and it is shared among the angles. Take care not to alter the `df` between tests.
- We load the `df` within the `generate_test_data` function, freeing the test from doing the setup part.

#### Update

If you want to control the names of the tests, use `pytest.param`. Replace `yield df, angle` with

```py
yield pytest.param(df, angle, id=f"df={filename}, angle={angle:>3}")
```

and you get the following output (note the names of the tests):

```
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set1.csv, angle=  0] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set1.csv, angle= 30] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set1.csv, angle= 60] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set2.csv, angle= 90] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set2.csv, angle=120] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set2.csv, angle=150] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set3.csv, angle=180] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set3.csv, angle=210] PASSED
test_combinations.py::test_df_against_angle[df=data_set3.csv, angle=240] PASSED
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator to parametrize multiple parameters. For example, if your test function takes as input a filename (the path to a CSV file) and a list of angles, you could write something like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("filename,angles", (
  ("data_set1.csv", (0, 30, 60)),
  ("data_set2.csv", (90, 120, 150)),
  ("data_set3.csv", (180, 210, 240)),
))
def test_df_against_angle(filename, angles):
  df = load_some_df(filename)
  ...
```

---

Given the new information you've left in your comments, you could write your test like this to get the desired nine parametrized tests:

```
import pytest

from itertools import product


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "filename,angle",
    (
        *product(("data_set1.csv",), (0, 30, 60)),
        *product(("data_set2.csv",), (90, 120, 150)),
        *product(("data_set3.csv",), (180, 210, 240)),
    ),
)
def test_angles(filename, angle):
    assert True
```

This will run the following tests:

```
$ pytest -v
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
collected 9 items

test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set1.csv-0] PASSED                                               [ 11%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set1.csv-30] PASSED                                              [ 22%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set1.csv-60] PASSED                                              [ 33%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set2.csv-90] PASSED                                              [ 44%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set2.csv-120] PASSED                                             [ 55%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set2.csv-150] PASSED                                             [ 66%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set3.csv-180] PASSED                                             [ 77%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set3.csv-210] PASSED                                             [ 88%]
test_angles.py::test_angles[data_set3.csv-240] PASSED                                             [100%]

=========================================== 9 passed in 0.01s ===========================================
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it did not work but when I changed it into `from pytest import mark` and then `@mark.parametrize("filename,angles", ( ` it worked well. Also I had to be careful about the relative paths of the files

Comment: Only one caveat: WIth this I got three tests, the first one with `data_set1.csv` and a tuple (`0,30,60)`. Ideally what I am looking for is to have nine tests, the first one dealing with `data_set1.csv` and 0, the second one with the same df and 30 etc.

Comment: I wonder if the only solution is to repeat the file names three times for each parameter  `@mark.parametrize("filename,angle", (    
  ("./test/data/data_1.csv", 0),("./test/data/data_1.csv", 30),("./test/data/data_1.csv", 60) ....`